# <li> tag Xpath location

Tags: java, xpath

There are many list elements in my xml with some class name:

```
<li class="name">
  <div>....</div>
  ......
</li>
```

Set location like "//*li[@class='name']" throws

`javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extra illegal tokens: 'LI', '[', '@', 'class', '=', ''name'', ']'`

How to get this list elements via xpath location?

Comment: If your xml contains HTML only, use a HTML parser instead like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: Does your XML include namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `*`, i.e. instead of

```
//*li[@class='name']
```

you need to use

```
//li[@class='name']
```

Comment: Yeah, after removing '*' exception doesn't throw, but my list is empty in such way. Using `//*[@class='name']` shows results, but i need to get these results only in <li> tag. Maybe i should take parent element then?

Comment: @AntonChertash it sounds like there might be a namespace issue.  Do you by any chance have `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` or similar at the root of your input file?

Answer (score 0):

That * is unnecessary, and if you want to search for all li elements matching your class at any level in the tree the * should just be removed.

- says "match all elements at this level of the tree" so "//*" basically says match all elements in the tree, and everything after the * is therefore invalid.